# Filtering a mousemove event from Mobile Safari long press

Tags: javascript, touch, mobile-safari, mousemove

I'm currently building a touch enabled slider widget intended for multiple browsers.  So, I have listeners for touchstart, touchend, touchmove, mousedown, mousemove, and mousedown.  It works great except on Mobile Safari.

If I long press on my target, a mousemove event fires with the coordinates of the previous touch causing jitter.

How do I prevent or filter out this mousemove event without causing problems with desktop interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Swipe JS ? http://swipejs.com/

Comment: No, the application is actually implemented in GWT.  But this isn't a GWT specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of events for a long press in mobile safari is touchstart, mousemove, touchend.  This is different from a valid mouse move (mousedown, mousemove, mouseup) and a valid touch (touchstart, touchmove, touchend).  If you call prevent default for all the valid events, you won't get extra notifications.  So, if you track that the slider is moving with a mouse independently from moving in response to touch, the mousemove occurs outside of a normal sequence and can be safely ignored.